# Template conflict for similar numerical types

Tags: c++, templates

I have a very simple function

```
template<typename T>
bool is_element(const std::vector<T> & vec, T el)
{
    return (std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), el) != vec.end());
}
```

that is supposed to just check if an element exists in a vector. But I run into problems when for example el is an unsigned long and vec is an integer vector. The template types are different initially, but the same after implicit conversion. Is there any elegant way to deal incorporate implicit conversion into templates without doing a bunch of function overloading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could deduce `T` using the first parameter, while suppressing type-deduction in the second one by putting it in a non-deducible context:

```
template<class T>
struct suppress_deduction {
    using type = T;
};

template<class T>
using suppress_deduction_t = typename suppress_deduction<T>::type;

template<typename T>
bool is_element(const std::vector<T> & vec, suppress_deduction_t<T> el)
{
    return (std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), el) != vec.end());
}
```

Comment: Also see [`std::type_identity_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) (c++20) which can be used in this fashion.

Answer (score 4):

Do you need to limit yourself to a single template type?

```
template<typename T, typename S>
bool is_element(const std::vector<T> & vec, S el)
{
    return (std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), el) != vec.end());
}
```

Comment: I guess this works, but in the vast majority of cases the templates will be the same type, so the second template parameter is redundant.

Comment: If the use case is 'usually the same type, but sometimes different' then the second type is not redundant.

Comment: What I mean is there is never a case where you want to find an object of type A inside a vector B, unless they are implicitly convertible.

Comment: @user2520385: Imagine a class `Person` which has `operator==` with other type (`std::string` with its name/id) but not a constructor with only that parameter (age would be required for example). So there are no conversions, but you can  search "by name" using `std::string`. And even if conversion is possible, you might avoid this extra construction with direct comparison (looking in `std::vector<std::string>` with a `const char*` without extra allocation).

Comment: I see, that makes sense

Answer (score 4):

You can make one parameter non deducible.

Following does that and also makes it more generic:

```
template <typename Container>
bool is_element(const Container& cont, const Container::value_type& e)
{
    return (std::find(cont.begin(), cont.end(), e) != cont.end());
}
```